# Функция отвечает только на второй/третий клик по слушателю

Tags: javascript, слайдер

Пытаюсь реализовать бесконечный слайдер, который в дальнейшем будет с плавной перемоткой. В данный момент не получается, чтобы перемотка запускалась при первом клике, только со второго или третьего.

```
const next = document.querySelector('.next'),// кнопка перемотки слайдов
         wrap = document.querySelector('.wrapper');// контейнер со слайдами

      const num = document.querySelectorAll('.num');// слайды (тут получаю для демонстрации)

// функция удаления первого слайда с переносом его в конец родителя
function childRemover() {
  let removed = wrap.removeChild(wrap.firstChild);
  wrap.appendChild(removed);
  }

// реализация слушателя
next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  childRemover();
});
```

Comment: `let removed = wrap.removeChild(wrap.firstChild);` эту строчку можно удалить, `appendChild` и так перенесёт элемент в конец.

Comment: Это не решает проблемы к сожалению.

Comment: потому что когда переносится первый child, остается текстовая нода-пробел, поэтому и работает через раз https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild

Comment: Честно говоря, манипуляция с dom в слайдере довольно неудачная идея. Особенно, если вы хотите еще и плавную перемотку. В классическом слайдере достаточно манипулировать положением контейнера. А для создания эффекта зацикливания добавьте -1 -ым слайдом n-ый и n+1 -ым слайдом нулевой и сразу после сдвига с n-го на n+1 переставьте контейнер на 0-ой слайд, а при сдвиге с 0-го на -1-й, переставьте на n-ый (без анимации). Вот так: [n, 0, 1, 2, ..., n-2, n-1, n, 0]

Comment: @Zombotron Если честно не совсем понял.
`next.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
    num.forEach((elem, i) => {
      if (i == 0) {
        i = num.length - 1;
  
      } else {
        i = i - 1;
      }
        offset = 100 * (i + 1);
        wrap.style.transform = `translateY(-${offset}px)`; 
    });
});
`
Все равно не работает, перемотка отдельно, анимация отдельно.

Comment: Мне лень сейчас разбираться в коде. )  Так: Листаете в одну сторону - 0 > 1 > 2 > ... > n-1 > n > n+1 >>> 0 > 1 > 2 > ... Листаете в другую - 2 > 1 > 0 > -1 >>> n > n-1 > n-2 > .... Тут > - плавный переход по клику на кнопку , >>> -  автопереход без анимации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если в разметке есть переносы строки или пробельные символы между слайдами, то перебираться будут и они (текстовые ноды или текстовые узлы), об этом говорится в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild). Поэтому необходимо фильтровать выборку дочернего элемента наподобие этого:

```js
const next = document.querySelector('.next'),// кнопка перемотки слайдов
         wrap = document.querySelector('.wrapper');// контейнер со слайдами

const num = document.querySelectorAll('.num');// слайды (тут получаю для демонстрации)

// функция удаления первого слайда с переносом его в конец родителя
function childRemover() {
  let removed = wrap.firstChild;
    while( removed.nodeType == 3){ // skip TextNodes
    removed = removed.nextSibling;
   }
   wrap.removeChild(removed);
   wrap.appendChild(removed);
}

// реализация слушателя
next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  childRemover();
});
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    
  </div>
  <button class="next">next</button>
```

Comment: Виноват)) Все отработало, спасибо!